# Consulta Filtrada ajax y metodo post

Tags: javascript, php, sql, ajax, post

> mi problema es que no se porque me manda error si creo que tengo todo correcto, el problemas es que quiero que me traiga solo la información que le estoy dando por metodo post en nro_boleta pero a la hora de correrlo me dice que tengo un error en SQL, me podrian apoyar, muchas gracias, les dejo el código, saludos

en administrar_venta.php estoy tomando el valor de nro_boleta de una variable, ya comprobe que si lo toma pero no se si la forma de enviar por el metodo post es correcto

## Archivo administra_venta.php

```
$('#lstVentas tbody').on('click', '.btnEditarVenta', function() {

        nroBoleta = $(this).attr("nroBoleta");

        $('#tblDetalleVenta').DataTable({
            columns: [

                {data: 'id'},
                {data: 'nro_boleta'},
                {data: 'codigo_producto'},
                {data: 'nombre_categoria'},
                {data: 'descripcion_producto'},
                {data: 'cantidad'},
                {data: 'total_venta'},

            ],

            processing: true,
            serverSide: true,
            paging: false,
            dom: 'rt',

            language: {
                url: "//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.20/i18n/Spanish.json"
            },

            ajax: {
                url: "ajax/EditTable/obtener_detalle_venta.php",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: 'json',
                data:{"nro_boleta": nroBoleta},
            }
        });


        $("#modalEditarVenta").modal('show')

    })
```

En obtener detalle esta el select pero a la hora de correrlo me manda el error "DataTables warning: table id=tblDetalleVenta - Invalid JSON response. For more information about this error, please see [http://datatables.net/tn/1"](http://datatables.net/tn/1%22)

## Archivo obtener_detalle_venta.php

```
<?php

require_once "../../modelos/conexion.php";

$query = "SELECT v.id,
                v.nro_boleta,
                v.codigo_producto,
                c.nombre_categoria,
                p.descripcion_producto,
                v.cantidad as cantidad,
                round(v.total_venta,2) as total_venta
                FROM venta_detalle v INNER JOIN productos p ON v.codigo_producto = p.codigo_producto
                INNER JOIN categorias c ON c.id_categoria = p.id_categoria_producto
                WHERE nro_boleta = " .$_POST['nro_boleta'] ." ORDER BY v.id";

$stmt = Conexion::conectar()->prepare($query);

$stmt->execute();

$numero_filas_filtradas = $stmt->rowCount();

$result = $stmt->fetchAll();

$output = array(
    'draw'  => intval($_POST['draw']),
    'recordsTotal' => $numero_filas_filtradas,
    'recordsFiltered' => $numero_filas_filtradas,
    'data'    => $result
);

echo json_encode($output);
```

> estas son mis tablas

[image: Tabla venta_detalle]

[image: Tabla productos]

[image: Tabla categorias]

Comment: ¿No será porque en nroBoleta no estás enviando un valor válido?

Comment: si le quito al select la sentencia WHERE me llama todos los datos correctamente, el problemas es nro_boleta

Comment: nroBoleta = $('#nroBoleta').val();

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0):

lo estoy tomando de aqui

```
drawCallback: function(settings) {

   var api = this.api();

   var rows = api.rows({
   page: 'current'
   }).nodes();
   var last = null;

   api.column(groupColumn, {
       page: 'current'
   }).data().each(function(group, i) {

       if (last !== group) {

           const data = group.split("-");
           var nroBoleta = data[0];
           nroBoleta = nroBoleta.split(":")[1].trim();
                            

         $(rows).eq(i).before(
        '<tr class="group">' +
        '<td colspan="6" class="fs-6 fw-bold fst-italic bg-dark text-white">' +
        '<i nroBoleta = ' + nroBoleta + ' class="fas fa-trash-alt fs-lg text-yellow mx-2 btnEliminarVenta" style="cursor:pointer;"></i><i nroBoleta = ' + nroBoleta + ' class="fas fa-edit fs-lg text-warning mx-2 btnEditarVenta" style="cursor:pointer;"></i> ' +
            group +
            '</td>' +
            '</tr>'
      );

   last = group;
  }
 });
},
```

sobra decir que soy principiante pero no entiendo porque me manda el error

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).